# How to set a FOREIGN KEY DEFERRABLE when using Fluent NHibernate and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate on PostgreSQL, I want to set that FOREIGN KEY are DEFERRABLE, but I can't find a way to customize anything but the name of the foreign keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to change it in Fluent NHibernate so I decided to alter the foreign keys that all are like fk% :

```
UPDATE pg_constraint SET condeferrable = 't' WHERE conname LIKE 'fk%';
UPDATE pg_trigger set tgdeferrable = 't' FROM pg_constraint
WHERE pg_constraint.oid = pg_trigger.tgconstraint 
    AND pg_constraint.conname like 'fk%' ;
```